# django - showing OrderedDict in templatetag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, ordereddictionary, templatetags

I have a OrderedDict and I need to show its key, value but I am unable to get its value, I have this dict = ([('sainbath', 'thesailor'), ('HELLO', 'WORLD')]), I have tried this

```
{{object.specifications}}
      <ul>
        <li>{% for key in object.specifications %}
          {{key}}
          {%endfor%}
```

I am getting this output

> OrderedDict([('sainbath', 'thesailor'), ('HELLO', 'WORLD')])
>
> - sainbath HELLO

I am getting its key only not value, when I tried this

```
{{object.specifications}}
      <ul>
        <li>{% for key,value in object.specifications %}
          {{key}} : {{value}}
          {%endfor%}
```

it give me error

> Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 8. 
>   please tell me how can I get value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Use following in template:

```
{% for key,value in object.specifications.items %}
      {{key}}:{{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

**OR**

2)If you are rendering a template with the data as OrderedDict, you can use following approach for the same.

```
return render_to_response('your_template.html',{'data': sorted(your_ordered_dict.iteritems())})
```

and in Template you can use the same as below:

```
{% for key, value in data %}
     {{key}}:{{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it will help you!!